# Lack of precision in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[
   xmin=120.,xmax=140.,
   ymin=120.,ymax=140.,
   grid=both,
   xlabel={$x$},
   ylabel={$y$},
   minor x tick num=2,
   minor y tick num=5,
   max space between ticks=30,
   axis lines=middle
   ]
   \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] table[x=X,y=Y] {
    X        Y
 119.5    120
 120.5    120
 120.5    121
 121.5    121
 121.5    122
 122.5    122
 122.5    123
 123.5    123
 123.5    124
 124.5    124
 124.5    125
 125.5    125
 125.5    126
 126.5    126
 126.5    127
 127.5    127
 127.5    128
 128.5    128
 128.5    129
 129.5    129
 129.5    130
 130.5    130
 130.5    131
 131.5    131
 131.5    132
 132.5    132
 132.5    133
 133.5    133
 133.5    134
 134.5    134
 134.5    135
 135.5    135
 135.5    136
 136.5    136
 136.5    137
 137.5    137
 137.5    138
 138.5    138
 138.5    139
 139.5    139
};
   \addplot [red,mark=|,mark size=1pt] table {
   X Y
   120 126
   150 126
   };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives me the following:
[image: Lack of precision? The red line is supposed to be y=126!]

There's a problem with the plotting. The red line is supposed to be at `y=126` and it is slightly above. And for example, the first blue dot (which has the coordinates `x=119.5`, `y=120`) at the bottom left is plotted at `(119.75,119)`.

How can I fix this?

I'm missing something here.

Regards.

Comment: Count the lines between 125 and 130, set `minor y tick num=4,`

Comment: As @RunarTrollet says. You want one less minor tick for both axes. (For example, with major ticks at 125 and 130, you want minor ticks at 126, 127, 128 and 129, i.e. four minor ticks, but you have told `pgfplots` to add five minor ticks.)

Comment: ...and the same on x axis --- use 1 or 3.

Comment: BTW next time please post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classical [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) (in two places) ☺

With `minor y tick num=4`, `minor x tick num=3`:

[image: correct grid]

Comment: Thank you. Did not count the ticks correcly.